# Subquery returned more than 1 value.This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql, subconsultas

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE INSERTUPDATEAVIOS
@ID_AVIOS INT,
@FACTURA VARCHAR(100),
@LOTE_MATERIAL VARCHAR(100),
@CANTIDAD DECIMAL(18,4),
@DISPONIBLE BIT,
@UBICACION INT,
@CREADOPOR VARCHAR(50),
@ACTUALIZADOPOR VARCHAR(50)
AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE @EXISTENCIA DECIMAL(18,4)
    DECLARE @CANTIDAD2 DECIMAL(18,4)

        IF EXISTS (SELECT ID_AVIOS FROM TBL_ENTRADA_AVIOS WHERE ID_AVIOS = @ID_AVIOS AND LOTE_MATERIAL = @LOTE_MATERIAL AND UBICACION = @UBICACION)

        BEGIN

             SET @EXISTENCIA = (SELECT ISNULL(CANTIDAD,0) FROM TBL_ENTRADA_AVIOS WHERE ID_AVIOS = @ID_AVIOS)

             SET @CANTIDAD2 = (@EXISTENCIA + @CANTIDAD)

             UPDATE TBL_ENTRADA_AVIOS SET CANTIDAD = @CANTIDAD2 WHERE ID_AVIOS = @ID_AVIOS
        END

        ELSE

        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO TBL_ENTRADA_AVIOS(ID_AVIOS,FACTURA,LOTE_MATERIAL,CANTIDAD,DISPONIBLE,UBICACION,CREADO,CREADOPOR,ACTUALIZADO,ACTUALIZADOPOR)
            VALUES(@ID_AVIOS,@FACTURA,@LOTE_MATERIAL,@CANTIDAD,@DISPONIBLE,@UBICACION,GETDATE(),@CREADOPOR,GETDATE(),@ACTUALIZADOPOR)

        END
END
```

Pero al momento de correrlo me manda el error (Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.)
Espero puedan ayudarme.
Gracias

Comment: Vas a tener que debuggear e ir parte por parte del SP. `TBL_ENTRADA_AVIOS WHERE ID_AVIOS = @ID_AVIOS` Tiene más de 1 registro. Probablemente sea un problema de entrada de datos o un mal diseño en algún punto del software. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El error viene de la siguiente linea:

```
SET @EXISTENCIA = (SELECT ISNULL(CANTIDAD,0) FROM TBL_ENTRADA_AVIOS WHERE ID_AVIOS = @ID_AVIOS)
```

La consulta regresa múltiples líneas y estás tratando de asignarle un valor escalar. Es probable que ID_AVIOS no sea una llave primaria y necesites columnas adicionales en tus condiciones. Además, será necesario modificar todo el código de tu procedimiento para ajustar a la llave compuesta.

En caso de que sea la llave primaria, es probable que no esté definida como tal en la tabla y tengas filas duplicadas.